# Environment default attributes

Tags: auctex

When I want to insert an environment in latex, I usually call `LaTeX-environment` by hitting `C-C C-e`. However, some environment requires extra parameters, like 'aligned' requires a position or 'proof' requires a title. In almost all cases I just hit enter to accept a default setting (no position or no title).

Is there a way to change this behavior so that for these environment the default option is always adopted with no extra interaction?

Comment: I'm not asked any parameter with `aligned` or `proof` (I use Emacs 25.2 and AUCTeX 12.1.1). Take a look at `C-h f LaTeX-environment`, it lists a few variables to set-up the interaction; for example, with `(setq LaTeX-default-position nil)` it inserts `tabular` environments without specifying the position nor asking for it.